# D3 - format elapsed time

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to d3.js but I really think this is a really powerful tool.

My problem today is formatting the time ticks.

I am having a live chart plotted with d3v5, with the time in the x-axis. The time is coded in milliseconds since the start of the page (time=0 after loading).
I would like the ticks to show 15s,30s,45s,:1,15s,30s,45s,:2,and so on.

My problem is, using the scaletime function, I actually end up with the year 1970 shown at the start.

Can anyone guide me? I have started to look at the formattick function, but didn't end up finding a way to do what I wish.

Can anyone show me a direction?

Thank you,

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by myself in the end.

I have changed my scale from timescale to scalelinear.
I have created a function that return the proper d3.format value based on an input integer

```
      var TimeFormatLive = function(d) {
    if (d < 0) {//checking a condition based on that do foarmat
      //provide a format
      return '';
    }
    else if (d ==0){
      //provide some other format  
      return ":" + d3.format(".0f")(d/1000);
  }
    else if (d % (3600*1000)==0){
        //provide some other format  
        return d3.format(".0f")(d/(3600*1000)) + "h"; 
    }
    else if (d % (60*1000)==0){
          //provide some other format  
          return d3.format(".0f")((d /(1000*60)) % 60) + "min"; 
    }
    else {
     //provide some other format  
     return ":" + d3.format(".0f")((d/1000) % 60 ) ; 
    }
  };
```

I then apply this "filter" to my .tick object

```
.call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(15).tickFormat(TimeFormatLive)
```